get_var not returning a value when the field contains an apostrophe
I am trying to run a comparison on 2 tables based on last names. However, if the fields contain apostrophes, the query returns a blank result. If it doesn't contain an apostrophe, it will return the correct result, either 0 or however many matches there are. Not sure if it matters, but both fields are text data types. My code is below. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_dir_table1 order by lname");
foreach ($sql as $sqlpers) {
    $lname = $sqlpers->lname;
    $ctr = $wpdb->get_var("select count(*) from wp_dir_table2 where lname='$lname'");
    echo $ctr . "<br>";
}


This is because the apostrophe used to enclose the lname= value is closed, which causes an invalid query, or at least a mismatch. Using the wpdb::prepare() method is recommended, or $lname = addslashes( $lname ); before the query.
As it stands, if $lname contains an apostrophe (ex: Jason's), here's what the SQL query looks like:
select count(*) from wp_dir_table2 where lname='jason's'

Using wpdb::prepare() or addslashes() will change it to this, which will work properly:
select count(*) from wp_dir_table2 where lname='jason\'s'


The addslashes($lname) worked. Thanks for the help.
